# Examples given in the Python BeautifulSoup 4 Documentation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning the BeautifulSoup 4 Documentation, and want to exercise the examples given.

I am trying the examples however it’s not successful. An example below.

It seems I am not putting it in the right way, and problem lies in the ‘url’. What is the right way to put them?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2


url = '<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

Learning = soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")

print Learning
```

Comment: This is the url you want: `"http://example.com/elsie"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>'` is not an url.

The code contains html; You don't need to use `urllib2.urlopen`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = '<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
Learning = soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
print Learning
```